# Regex to convert 2-digitno to 3-digitno

Tags: regex, notepad++

I had a requirement where in my file I had to replace all 2-digitno occurrences to corresponding 3-digitno.

For example:

- `48` should be replaced by `048`.
- `02` should be replaces by `002`.

Till now I am able to identify 2 digit nos in my document with expression:

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

But I am not able to figure out how to append `0` to no. Kindly help me in writing regular expression for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: What OS and program are you using to do this?

Comment: Hi Gary, since I have a long document, I am simply using replace feature of Notepad++ application on Windows7

Comment: Till now I am able to identify 2 digit nos in my document with expression : ^[0-9]{2}$ ..........But I am not able to figure out how to append 0 to no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the Search and Replace dialog:

Find what:      `\b\d{2}\b`
Replace with: `0$0`

Note that `^[0-9]{2}$` means *match 2 digits from the beginning of the line till end*. So, if you have several numbers and not equaling the whole line, your regex would not work.

`\b` is a word boundary, and makes sure there is a letter, digit or an underscore before/after the word.

[image]

Comment: This worked.understood usage of \b. Wanted to ask how regex 0$0 coverted no by appending it with 0.

Comment: `$0` is a backreference to the whole text matched by the regex pattern. It will hold 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace the result of following regex :

```
/\b(\d\d)\b/g
```

to :

```
/0\1/
```

or for capturing the group in some regex engines use `$1`

Comment: Kasramvd, I am using replace feature of  Notepad++ application